# Find the range for this function $f(x)=\sqrt {x^2+2x+2} - x$

Tags: calculus, functions

> $$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
>   $f(x)=\sqrt {x^2+2x+2} - x$

I do get $f'(x)$ $<0\Rightarrow f$ is decreasing on $\mathbb R$, but how can I find the range for this function?

Comment: By "set of values" do you mean "the range"?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the range. I'm not very friendly with math english terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
$$y+x=\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}$$
you get that
$$y+x\geq 0$$
Squaring both sides and simplifying gives
$$x(2y-2)=2-y^2$$
hence
$$x=\frac{2-y^2}{2y-2}$$
Impose the consition $y+x\geq 0$ and find
$$\frac{y^2-2y+2}{2y-2}\geq 0$$
which is satisfied by
$$y>1$$

Answer (score 1):

Note

\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sqrt{x^2+2x+2} - x \\
&=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1} - (x+1)+1 \\
 &=\frac1{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1} + (x+1)}+1 > 1\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You have that $f$ is decreasing on all of $R$.   So if you compute the limits as $x \to -\infty$ and $x\to +\infty$ you will have the range.

Comment: I do not understand this. Why I need to calculate the limits both to −∞, and +∞? Both are 1, so the range is {1} ?

Comment: The first limit is not $1$.

Comment: It is -1, thanks for your help. I will accept the other answer as I understand much better

Comment: It is not $-1$.   How could a function be always decreasing and somehow get from $-1$ at $-\infty$  to $+1$ at $+\infty$?

Comment: Well thanks for your questions. I'm just a new learner in mathematics, try to learn new things every day. Maybe a more explicitly answer from you, and not N questions, could help me more

Comment: Giving a student a detailed answer doesn't help them learn.  Questions guide them into real learning.  If you're just here to get free answers to your homework questions, then you're cheating.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}-x$

For $x < 0$, we get $f(x) > -x=|x|$, hence $f(x)$ approaches infinity as $x$ approaches minus infinity.

Thus $f$ is unbounded above.

For $x \ge -1$, we have
\begin{align*}
f(x)
&=\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}-x\\[4pt]
&=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}-x\\[4pt] 
& > \sqrt{(x+1)^2}-x\\[4pt]
&=|x+1|-x\\[4pt]
&=(x+1)-x\\[4pt]
&=1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
As you noted, $f$ is strictly decreasing, hence $1$ is a strict lower bound for the range of $f$.

As $x$ approaches infinity, we have
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)-1\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}-(x+1)\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}-(x+1)\right){\cdot\,}
\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}+(x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}+(x+1)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(x^2+2x+2)-(x+1)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}+(x+1)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}+(x+1)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\frac{1}{\infty}\\[6pt]
=\;&\;0
\end{align*}
hence ${\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)}}=1$.

Since $f$ is continuous, it follows that the range of $f$ is $(1,\infty)$.